# How to convert a monochrome image to an alpha mask?

Tags: gimp

I have this simple image that is intended to be used as a background for a desktop program. How can I alter this image into a sort of mask? For example, making the lighter areas more transparent (75% opacity) than the darker areas (50% opacity).

I am searching for a solution preferably using GIMP or other free software, but any general guidance would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Layer>Mask>Add layer mask
- Initialize the mask to "Grayscale copy of mayer", and check the "Invert mask" button.

But you will have to add more contrast to the mask for more visible difference in opacity (as done below).

[image]

("plasma" layer added for demonstration purposes)